# Index multiple non-adjacent elements of a Fortran array

Tags: fortran

Is there a way in Fortran to access many elements of an array without using a loop?

For example given array of 100 elements

```
real(100) :: a
```

can I do something like this to access elements 1,4,7,54,81 that do not follow a regular step?

```
a(1,4,7,54,81)= 3.21423
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted before, an array may be used as the indexes of an array.  This is a so-called vector subscript.

```
A([1,4,7,54,81]) = 3.21423
```

sets the elements given to that value.  (This is the same as the earlier answer but using the Fortran 2003+/modern array constructor notation.)

The array can be any rank-1 array, such as a variable or expression:

```
integer :: idx(5)=[1,4,7,54,81]
A(idx) = 3.21423
A(idx-1+1) = 3.21423
```

Of course, vector subscripts are of use in other settings, such as referencing:

```
print *, A(idx)
call sub(A(idx))
A(idx) = A(idx+1) + 5
```

However, array sections with vector subscripts are subject to various restrictions, such as:

1. not always may they be arguments to a procedure;
2. a pointer may not point to them;
3. not all such sections may be assigned to.

In the third case, if the same index appears more than once in the subscript we can't define it.  So

```
print *, A([1,5,1])
```

is allowed, but

```
A([1,5,1]) = 3.
```

is not.

Comment: print *, A([1,5,1]) is not working for me, I  get "Error: Fortran 2003: [...] style array constructors at (1)"

Comment: If you are stuck with using Fortran 90/95 code, then use `(/1,5,1/)` rather than `[1,5,1]`.

Answer (score 7):

you could use a vector subscript: `a( (/1,4,7,54,81/) )= 3.21423`

Answer (score -2):

RESHAPE and WHERE are worth looking at.
If you are determining which elements to 'pull out' then maybe ALLOCATE a new variable and stuff the elements of A into B.
Maybe something like this:

```
REAL,    DIMENSION(100)            :: A
LOGICAL, DIMENSION(100)            :: A_Mask
INTEGER                            :: SizeB
REAL,    DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: B
!...
A_Mask = .FALSE.
WHERE(A > 1.0)
  A_Mask = .TRUE.
ENDWHERE
SizeB = SUM(A_Mask)
!... then allocate B and fill it.
```

Comment: The argument to SUM must be of numeric type.  The language has an intrinsic to `COUNT` true values in a logical array expression.  I don't think the code in this answer addresses the question in any useful way.

Comment: Not only is this answer way off beam, it also looks as if its author is suggesting a home-brewed alternative to the `pack` function !