# Sum Function in Fortran

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sum, fortran, gfortran, fortran90

I am working through a piece of Fortran90 code and got stuck at the sum function. The code doe not work properly at this point.

The relevant piece of code goes as follows:

```
subroutine barfilter(xp,neighbbar,nelem,pe)
integer*4, intent(in), dimension(:,:)  :: neighbbar
real*8, intent(in)                     :: pe
real*8, intent(inout), dimension(:)    :: xp
integer*4                              :: nbar, bar
real*8                                 :: total

nbar = size(neighbbar,1)
do bar = 1,nbar
    total = sum(xp(neighbbar(bar,:))**pe,1,neighbbar(bar,:)>0))
end do
end subroutine
```

I do unterstand the consturction of the sum function. However the formulation

```
xp(neighbbar(bar,:))
```

I do not understand. When dubugging in Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 and typing it in, it just says "{...}" as a result. What does that mean?

Comment: That is vector subscripting of the array `xp`, as can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/fortran/996/arrays/30566/advanced-array-sections-subscript-triplets-and-vector-subscripts) or in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39379124).

Comment: Are you sure you have gfortran in MS Visual Studio?

Comment: I would be very surprised if it DID work.  You are using the `neighbor` array to mask the `xp` array.  Perhaps the mask should be `xp(neighbbar(bar,:))>0`?